# how to load a Kafka topic to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka

I am using hortonworks sandbox.
**creating topic**:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 10.25.3.207:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic lognew
```

**tailing the apache access log directory**:

```
tail -f  /var/log/httpd/access_log |./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.25.3.207:6667 --topic lognew
```

**At another terminal (of kafka bin) start consumer**:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 10.25.3.207:2181 --topic lognew --from-beginning
```

The apache access logs are sent to the kafka topic "**lognew**".

I need to store them to HDFS.
Any ideas or suggestions regarding how to do this.

Thanks in advance.
Deepthy

Answer (score 6):

we use [camus](https://github.com/linkedin/camus).

> Camus is a simple MapReduce job developed by LinkedIn to load data
>   from Kafka into HDFS. It is capable of incrementally copying data from
>   Kafka into HDFS such that every run of the MapReduce job picks up
>   where the previous run left off. At LinkedIn, Camus is used to load
>   billions of messages per day from Kafka into HDFS.

But it looks like it's replaced with [gobblin](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin)

> Gobblin is a universal data ingestion framework for extracting,
>   transforming, and loading large volume of data from a variety of data
>   sources, e.g., databases, rest APIs, FTP/SFTP servers, filers, etc.,
>   onto Hadoop. Gobblin handles the common routine tasks required for all
>   data ingestion ETLs, including job/task scheduling, task partitioning,
>   error handling, state management, data quality checking, data
>   publishing, etc. Gobblin ingests data from different data sources in
>   the same execution framework, and manages metadata of different
>   sources all in one place. This, combined with other features such as
>   auto scalability, fault tolerance, data quality assurance,
>   extensibility, and the ability of handling data model evolution, makes
>   Gobblin an easy-to-use, self-serving, and efficient data ingestion
>   framework.

Comment: Thank you for you reply ...  **I tried to run camus but getting the following error:**  com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoderException: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.linkedin.camus.example.schemaregistry.DummySchemaRegistry

Comment: I guess you need to properly setup the project: http://etl.svbtle.com/setting-up-camus-linkedins-kafka-to-hdfs-pipeline

Comment: Other than using camus and gobblin is there any other way to load kafka topic to hdfs?

Comment: We have stopped on camus because it's successfully used in linkedin. I guess you can find other ways but camus and goblin are most popular for this moment.

Answer (score 2):

You have several other options as well:

- Use Apache Flume to read messages from Kafka and write them to your HDFS. There are several examples of how you can set it up, but one [article from Cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/flafka-apache-flume-meets-apache-kafka-for-event-processing/) covers that topic quite well. They even named the solution Flafka ;)
- Use [Kafka HDFS Connector](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html), which is quite simple to set up. However, it would require Confluent Kafka (which still is open sourced).

We tested both quite successfully.

Comment: If possible add content from the links to your answer. This way, if the links go dead, your answer is still useful

Comment: They're quite big articles, but I will try to explain some of the concepts.

Comment: How do you compile kafka hdfs connector? It says it needs common and schema repository master which I downloaded but I am unable to build using instructions at https://github.com/confluentinc/common. Filed a bug: https://github.com/confluentinc/common/issues/37